# rhdf5 package and arrays in R - storage mode list vs double

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, hdf5

I am using the package rhdf5 to build a large h5 with climate data for a specific geographic domain.

Domain has a dimension of 48x47 (lonxlat) points in space.
Climate variables (precipitation, temperature...) are organized in a matrix of 2256 rows (48*47=2256) and 248 columns (8 observation/day for a 31 days month).

In order to satisfy the requirements of the destination model, I need to structure the h5 dataset in the form (time, lon, lat) (248,48,47). That for, I transformed the matrix of the observations in an array of dimension  c(48,47,248) (lon,lat, time) and then used the command 'aperm' to switch the order of the dimensions.

However, when I write the dataset in the h5 file, I get the following message:
"Writing of this type of data not supported."

Here the code I am using:

```
# load package from bioconductor
require(rhdf5)

setwd("path/to/file")

lon <-read.csv("lon_h5.csv", header=FALSE)
lon <-as.matrix(lon) #matrix 48x47
lat <-read.csv("lat_h5.csv", header=FALSE)
lat<-as.matrix(lat) #matrix 48x47

h5createFile("file.h5")
h5createDataset("file.h5", "lon",c(48,47), storage.mode = "double")
h5createDataset("file.h5", "lat",c(48,47), storage.mode = "double")
h5write(lon, file="file.h5", name="lon")
h5write(lat, file="file.h5", name="lat")

tmp <-read.csv(file="temperature.csv", header=TRUE)
tmp = array(tmp,dim=c(48,47,248)) # it loops the 48 longitude points first, then the 47 latitude points, then 248 time steps
tmp = aperm(a=tmp,perm=c(3,1,2)) # switch the order of the dimensions, putting time first, then longitude, then latitude
h5createDataset("file.h5", "tmp",c(248,48,47), storage.mode = "double")
h5write(tmp, file="file.h5", name="tmp")

'Writing of this type of data not supported.'
```

The array has 559488 elements (48*47*248), so it should not be a problem of dimensions.

There is no problem when I write a matrix, as for the lon and lat matrices. Does anybody know if the package rhdf5 has problems with arrays?

Thank you

UPDATE:
Apparently the problem is related to the fact that the array has a 'list' storage mode that is not implemented in the rhdf5 package.

Somebody suggested me to change the storage mode of tmp using

```
storage.mode(tmp)="double"
```

but this wouldn't work (Error in storage.mode(tmp) = "double" : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double').
I tried instead

```
tmp<-as.numeric(unlist(tmp))
```

but this would change the dimension of my array from 559488 elements to 1262204908 (!!!) elements.
Other suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody is interested to the solution of this problem, it could be found here:

https://support.bioconductor.org/p/64651/#64682